# Detecting a change in a CSV row

Tags: python, csv, selenium

I am trying to find a way to detect when string elements in csv file change values. When the value changes, I want the operation of the program to change. I want to read the value in the for loop one step ahead and compare it to the current value. Unfortunately my research has only turn up results that step the for loop ahead by one rather than simply reading the value.

Any help would be appropriated.

```
import csv

with open("bleh.csv", "r") as bleh:
    blehFileReader = csv.reader(bleh, delimiter=',')
    next(blehFileReader, None)


    for row in blehFileReader:
        name = row
        nextname = next(blehFileReader)

        print(name)

        if name != nextname:
            print ("name has changed")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looking at the next name, look at the previous one:

```
previous_name = None

for row in blehFileReader:
    if row != previous_name:
        print ("name has changed")
        ....
    previous_name = row
```

Comment: I think that `if row != previous_name:` is enough. `row` cannot be `None`.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually better than what I was looking for.